# How can I append the file foo2.txt to foo1.txt?

Tags: perl, append

Is there any method to execute *foo2.pl* from *foo1.pl* in Perl, and append the *foo2.txt* to the *foo1.txt* then create *foo3.txt*? thanks.

i.e.

**foo1.pl**

```
 print "Hello"; # output to foo1.txt;
```

**foo2.pl**

```
 print "World"; # output to foo2.txt;
```

How to create *foo3.txt* file based on *foo1.pl*.

**foo3.txt**

```
Hello
World
```

Something like append *foo2.txt* to *foo1.txt*.

As i know, I can open *foo1.txt* and *foo2.txt*, then include the lines in *foo3.pl*.

```
print FOO3_TXT (<FOO1_TXT>);
print FOO3_TXT (<FOO2_TXT>);
```

Is there any good method?

---

Update my test (ActivePerl 5.10.1)

My foo.pl

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

print "world\n";
```

my *hw.pl* (foo.pl and hw.pl at the same directory)

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

print 'hello '; 
print `./foo.pl`;
```

Output

**D:\learning\perl>hw.pl

> hello '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.**

If hw.pl updated {}:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

print q{hello }, qx{./foo.pl};
```

Now Output. (a little different for the loacation of **hello**)

**D:\learning\perl>hw.pl
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
hello**

[Update].

Fixed. see answer,

Comment: re: Your update - see my last comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are being literal about `execute foo2.pl from foo1.pl in Perl` then this is what you can do:

```
print 'hello ';
print qx(perl foo2.pl);
```

[`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) is another way to run system commands like backticks.  Thus `perl foo2.pl` is run with the output being sent back to your calling perl script.

So here the same using backticks. Also it uses a direct call to script (which is better):

```
print 'hello ';
print `./foo2.pl`;
```

And if you are expecting lots of output from the script then its best not to load it all into memory like above two examples.  Instead use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) like so:

```
print 'hello ';
open my $foo2, '-|', './foo2.pl';
print <$foo2>;
close $foo2;
```

And you can wrap this up into one print statement for "hello world" example:

```
print 'hello ', do {
   open my $foo2, '-|', './foo2.pl';
   <$foo2>;
};
```

/I3az/

Comment: Hi draegtun, I run your script and show the error message: "hello '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.: Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Btw, I think <code>print 'hello '; print `./foo2.pl`; </code> is what i want!

Comment: Hi Nano HE, The error sounds like something hasn't copy/pasted over properly and perhaps its mangling those single quote into backticks?  When I copy my first example here it all works fine.  So try this Perl snippet:  `print q{hello }, qx{./foo2.pl};`

Comment: Hi. Still can't work. I don't know why? I updated my detail testing at my post.

Comment: Windows eh!  The `./foo2.pl` is *nix specific so doesn't work on barebones Windows by the looks of it.  Change it to a proper Windows path and it will work fine. So for an executable script then: `print q{hello }, qx{C:\path\foo2.pl};` should hopefully work now!

Answer (score 2):

run this as a script

```
perl foo1.pl > foo3.txt;
perl foo2.pl >> foo3.txt;
```

contents of foo1.pl

```
!#/bin/perl
print "Hello";
```

contents of foo2.pl

```
!#/bin/perl
print "World";
```

or

simply use the `cat` command if you are running linux to append foo2.txt to foo1.txt.

Comment: Hi iamrohitbanga, I tested with windows command line one by one. It works well. But i don't know how to write the script. Could i create the scipt as a **.pl** file? thank you.

Comment: I created a **try.bat** include `perl foo1.pl > foo3.txt; perl foo2.pl >> foo3.txt;` It works. thank you.

Comment: if it satisfies your need mark it as an answer. i haven't answered many questions before.

Comment: Hi iamrohitbanga, Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Using a shell script (for example, a `.bat` file on Windows) to run various Perl scripts and combine their output is one way to solve the problem. However, I usually find that Perl itself provides a more powerful and flexible environment than shell scripts. To use Perl in this way, one place to start is by learning about the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) commands.

For example:

```
# In hello.pl
print "Hello\n";

# In world.pl
print "World\n";

# In hello_world.pl.
use strict;
use warnings;
system 'perl hello.pl >  hello_world.txt';
system 'perl world.pl >> hello_world.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code also

file1.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FH,">file") or die "$! can't open";
print FH "WELCOME\n";
```

file2.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FH,">>file") or die "$! can't open";
print FH "WELCOME2\n";
```

The file content is

```
WELCOME 
WELCOME2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforhand that the script you want to execute from inside the other script is also Perl, you should use `do EXPR` (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).
This executes the contents of the file `EXPR` in the context of the running perl process and saves you from starting new cmd.exe and perl.exe instances.

```
hello.pl:
print "Hello";
do "world.pl";

wordl.pl:
print "World";
```